# Angular JS: ng-disabled not disabling button after submit

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like below-

```
 <form class="form-horizontal register-form" name="register" ng-submit="registerUser();" novalidate>
     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="email" class="form-control"  ng-model="user.email"  name="email" id="mail"  placeholder="Enter your Email"  required />
                 <i ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$invalid && !user.submit" class="error-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                 <i ng-show="register.email.$valid" class="valid-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            </div>
         <span class="error" ng-show="register.email.$dirty  && !user.submit && register.email.$invalid">Email field is required.</span>
           <span class="error" ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$error.email && register.email.$invalid">Email you entered is invalid.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.login_password" name="login_password" id="login_password"  placeholder="Enter your Password" required />
                 <i ng-show="register.login_password.$dirty && register.login_password.$invalid && !user.submit" class="error-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></i>
                 <i ng-show="register.login_password.$valid" class="valid-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="error" ng-show="register.login_password.$dirty && register.login_password.$error.required && !user.submit">Password field is required.</span>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirm" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                <input type="password"  ng-model="user.confirm_password" class="form-control" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password"  placeholder="Confirm your Password" required />
                <i ng-show="user.login_password !== user.confirm_password" class="error-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                 <i ng-show="register.confirm_password.$valid && user.login_password == user.confirm_password" class="valid-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="error" ng-show="register.confirm_password.$dirty && register.confirm_password.$error.required && !user.submit">Confirm password field is required.</span>
            <span class="error" ng-show="register.confirm_password.$dirty && user.login_password !== user.confirm_password">Confirm password does not match.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group ">
     {{register.$invalid }} {{  disableButton}}  {{register.$invalid ==  disableButton}}
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary login-button"  ng-disabled="register.$invalid"  id="button-register" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Registering..."><i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my conroller-

```
 $scope.registerUser = function() {  
        $scope.user.created_at =  Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        $scope.user.updated_at =  Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
        $scope.user.action =  'add';
        $("#button-register").button('loading');
         $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/user.php/users/', 
             data: $scope.user ,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
            $("#button-register").button('reset');

            $scope.successMsg = 'Congratulation! you are registered successfully.';
            $scope.user={};
            $scope.user.submit=true;
            $scope.disableButton=true;
        })



     } // End of register function
```

Everything works fine, but once I submit the form and clear the input fields the submit button is enabled. I tried to print the value of  {{register.$invalid }} after submit which is true(ideally if it is true button should be disabled). but still the button is enabled. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something do with this line :

```
$("#button-register").button('reset');
```

Maybe ,it's changing the submit into a whole new button with type reset.And so there is ng-disabled tag after the execution that statement.Try removing this statement and to see if the disable works without it.

Also its a jquery,which can always create a problem when it comes to combining it with angularjs.If that is the case try putting it in

```
 $scope.$apply(function(){
 $("#button-register").button('reset');
 }
```

Comment: You are correct @Neel. This code is the culprit.
  $("#button-register").button('reset');

But I am not understanding how to apply your code I mean the below part -
 
    $scope.$apply(function(){
    $("#button-register").button('reset');
    }

I added in .success block like below but its giving error.
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.successMsg = 'Congratulation! you are registered successfully.';
  $scope.user={};
  $scope.user.submit=true;
   $scope.$apply(function(){
        $("#button-register").button('reset');
 });
   })

Comment: Apply it as it is.Just remove your $("#button-register").button('reset') statement and paste the code i have written in the place of it.Hopefully,it should work.

Comment: I did that but no luck

Comment: oh ok ,can you press f12 and check if it is saying that $digest  already in progress something like that.If that's the case ,then i guess you have to find some way to do that reset thing using angular js instead of jquery.There ways to solve it ,but its situational and i don't know what in your case is causing the digest problem.

Comment: Console shows something like -
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest